# Redis Enterprise Cluster aware client

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

Can anyone explain to me what is **aware client** in Redis Enterprise ?

I found this post: [Redis Enterprise Clustering Command Error 'CLUSTER'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60530287/redis-enterprise-clustering-command-error-cluster)

I try to use Redis Enterprise Cluster with docker.
I create 3 docker redis nodes with two shards for better scalability.

[image]

So what exactly is that aware client and what is the difference between non-cluster aware ?

Also, what is **regular OSS cluster** ?

Thank You..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Cluster Aware" means a Redis client that supports the OSS Cluster API (https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec). For example, the Ruby client https://github.com/redis/redis-rb#cluster-support supports it.

A non-aware client is a client that only supports connecting to Redis in single-instance mode (and perhaps Sentinel), such as the Python client https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py.

The Enterprise Cluster can be used by both types of clients regardless of how the database is deployed (i.e. clustered or not).

To clear some more of the confusion:

- OSS Cluster - a mode of deployment and API (i.e. not single-instance)
- Enterprise Cluster - a product

Comment: Thank you Itamar, that will help :)